# Stuck at Checkout magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, checkout

I am looking for some help.  I am new into magento, and I don't have a lot of experience programming/debugging.  So I will appreciate any help; as I have been trying to figure this out for the last 2 days.

I have two problems, Here they are:

1) I add a product to the cart, then I go to the REGULAR checkout (NOT the express checkout), where I am asked to register; I click on the "register" button where I am asked to fill in the "billing information".  After filling in all the billing information I hit on the "Continue" button and...
... Nothing happens.  It stays stuck there.

2) When selecting the REGULAR checkout, I have noticed that the "YOUR CHECKOUT PROGRESS" doesn't show any of the progress; and it shows only the tittle instead.

---

I must tell you this:
a) When changing the theme to rwd/default the Checkout works perfectly.  Therefore I have understood that there is a file (or a script) that is not working properly inside the custom theme.  But I can't figure out which file/ script it is.

b) when chaging the theme to rwd/default the "checkout progress" column appears on the right and not on the left <-- just wondering is this piece of information may help to fix the problem.

I am new into debugging so I still have a lot to learn.  So any guide and specific help is more then welcome.  Thank you in advance.

I am using magento 1.9.2.2

This is the store:
http://www.mazentic.com/mentalgram.html

thanks

Nef

Comment: In my effort to find a solution to this I did the following:
On magento:
System/Configuration/Developer/Log settings

I enabled log settings.

later went to my store and tried to proceed to checkout, where i got stuck.

It was now time to open and read the log file.  I went to my cpanel to retrieve the log file, but then I discover that there was no 'log' directory inside of the 'var' directory.  

I created the directory and made sure that both 'var' and 'log' directory had a 777 permission.
I made an other failed checkout and tried to retrieve the log file, but again there was no log file.

Comment: It might be client-side javascript issue that is why it stucks and also the log is not being generated. I will suggest you to open browser console while going through the steps and check if any exception errors being logged in the console. I'm suggesting this only to see if you get an idea about the issue.

Comment: @elembivos
thank you for the idea, I tried it, but I got no exception errors at all when being logged in the browser console.

Comment: Okay, try this. In the console type these keywords one by one and press enter. `checkout`, `payment`, `billing`, `shipping`, `review`. If all the checkout objects are properly working then you will get objects returned. If any of those objects are not properly initialized it will return you 'undefined'.